# Part of return on asset uncorrelated with market

Tags: capm, beta

I've been told (and have done problems) involving the part of the return of an asset $X$ that is uncorrelated with returns on the market $M$, which can be written as $X - \beta X$. This sort of makes sense, but if someone asked me to explain what "the part of $X$ that is uncorrelated with $M$" is, I would've guessed $X - \beta M$ (per the Pythagorean theorem).

Is there an intuitive explanation for this? I guess $X - \beta M$ is not actually parallel to $X$ in general, so it's not "part of $X$" in that sense, but still.

I suppose this is very similar to "total risk = systematic risk + nonsystematic risk," which makes sense financially, but is also strange to me because I would think we would need to appeal to Pythagoras to get an additive identity.

Comment: That is strange, I would have though the "uncorrelated part" is $X-\beta M$

Comment: $X - \beta M$ is orthogonal to $M$. This isn't about finance as much as it's a basic consequence of ordinary least squares linear regression. At an even more foundational level, it's about [linear algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projection_(linear_algebra)) and [projection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_projection).

Comment: @MatthewGunn yes that was/is my argument, but the book (?) I was reading said $X - \beta X$

Comment: @Seh-kai What ordinary least squares does in linear algebra terms is to project the left hand side variable onto the linear space spanned by the right hand side variables. What's left over, the residual, is orthogonal to that space. Geometrically, it's like finding the shortest vector from a point to a plane; that vector (the residual) will then be orthogonal the plane (and any vector inside). This is somewhat tricky stuff at first, but once you really understand ordinary least squares in linear algebra terms, you can think about what regression is with more clarity and visual intuition.